# How to set csv file to open in the browser instead of download on Site Ground account

Tags: csv, file

I have a simple code that save logs in a 'csv' file on the server.

When I navigate to from the browser to the folder where the file is saved, clicking the file download it instead of opening the file for view in the browser.

I have another site using the same code exactly on the same server, and clicking file from it, open the file for view in the browser.

I use the same browser for both sites, so it is not related to browser settings.
I've tried to change the file privileges, but it didn't help.

This site was originally with a different host, and I thought that moving it to the same host will solve it, but it didn't.

I've tried to talk with the support of the hosting provider, but they say that a developer should handle it.

Comment: This can be a web server configuration issue, coding issue or browser issue. If it's the same code and browser my guess is web server configuration.

Comment: What kind of server configuration can it be?

Comment: Apache, IIS, Nginx e.g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the file ending to 'cvs' solved the problem, and opened the file in the browser without any other settings change.